# How can we prove that this set of probability density functions is compact

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Fix a constant real $A>1$. Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to [0, \infty)$ be a probability density function on $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx =1$, 
that is continuous almost everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$ and satisfying the condition:

$\forall x, x^\prime$ where $|x-x^\prime|\leq D$, it holds $f(x) \leq A f(x^\prime)$

Let $S$ be the set of all the functions meeting the above conditions.
Is $S$ compact ? How can we prove/disprove it ?

Comment: In the title `closed' should be replaced by `compact'. Sorry for the typo. Also assume $D>0$ is constant.

Comment: Whats the topology on $S$?

Comment: Maybe Arzela-Ascoli would work here?

Comment: Typically when one talks about convergence of probability measures, one means weak* convergence, i.e. convergence in distribution.

Comment: thanks Arkamis. Good point! Arzela-Ascoli works on closed intervals $[a,b]$ which is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

The set $S$ is not sequentially compact (in the probabilist's sense of convergence in distribution).
Let $f$ be any probability measure satisfying the above condition. Then set $f_n(x) := f(x-n)$. Clearly each $f_n$ also has the above property, so we have a sequence in $S$. However, the sequence cannot have a convergent subsequence since the corresponding CDF's are not tight. (Nonzero means it some set has positive mass, and shifting that mass off to infinity destroys tightness).

Reference about tightness: see lemma (a) on page 184 of [David Williams: Probability With Martingales](http://books.google.com/books?id=e9saZ0YSi-AC&pg=PA184#v=onepage&q&f=false) (google books link).

Comment: Thanks `nullUser' for your answer and the reference. I think I see your point. But what if we add another condition that $f(x)=f(-x)$. In this will we have tightness ? Is it compact in this case ? Sorry for my poor experience !

Comment: Thanks 'user15464' your question about topology! In fact I am open for this point. But I think any topology defined by a metric is acceptable. One example for metrics which I tried is the supremum one $d(f_1,f_2)=sup |f_1(x)-f_2(x)|$. But unfortunately I could not work it out.

Comment: nullUser, I am still wondering why you assumed weak convergence. For deciding the (sequential) compactness, we should use the convergence with respect to a metric, right ? (I don't think they are equivalent) I will appreciate your answer !

Comment: @ems When talking about convergence of probability measures, weak convergence (i.e. convergence in distribution) is the natural choice. E.g. in Williams above, that is the *only* type of convergence of measures discussed. If you want metric convergence, you should provide the metric. Also note that the sup or infinity metric is actually a pseudo-metric unless you quotient by the a.e. equivalence relation. (Quotienting is much more common outside of probability than inside) Anyway, to talk about compactness, you need to specify a topology, so if you have one in mind please let us know.

Comment: Well, my objective is to know if one of these pdfs gives a minimum expected error (I though compactness of $S$ is a step in this). Please give a look at my other question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461410/is-there-a-probability-density-function-providing-the-least-expected-value

Comment: I wish to find any metric that ensures compactness. For example I tried the sup with quotient by a.e. but it does not assure that the limit $lim_{n\to\infty} f_n$ respects $\int f(x) d x=1$, unless I missed something.