# Is there a probability density function providing the least expected value?

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Fix constant reals $A>1$ and $D>0$. Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to [0,\infty)$ be a probability density function on $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx=1$, that is continuous almost everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$ and satisfying the condition:

$\forall x,x′$ where $|x−x′|\leq D$, it holds $f(x)\leq A\,f(x′)$

Let $S$ be the set of these functions. Is there an optimal one $\hat f$ which gives the minimum expected error:

$E_f[|x|]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x|\, f(x)\, d x$

P.S. If it helps, we can assume that $f$ is symmetric i.e. $f(x)= f(-x)$. Note that the expected value is lower bounded by $0$, i.e. there is an infimum. I just need to show that there is a minimum (not necessary to find it).

Comment: I am ready to bet that the optimal density is the double exponential $f(x)=\frac12c\mathrm e^{-c|x|}$ with $\mathrm e^{cD}=A$, then $E[|x|]=1/c=D/\log A$.

Comment: Strong and interesting answer ! why?

Comment: Because this seems the way to put as much of the mass as close to zero as possible while meeting the condition on the variation of the density.

Comment: Great intuition, but many functions have the same behaviour, especially that $f$ is continuous a.e., which means restricted discontinuities are still allowed.

Comment: I did not say *how much* I was ready to bet...

Comment: The space of these functions is convex. Does it help ?

Answer (score 1):

See my answer at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138730/. In particular, Did's answer is correct in the limit $D \to 0$, but for finite $D$ one can do a bit better ;-)